# Jetbrains Rider not push to remote branch

Tags: git, rider

I'm using Jetbrains Rider 2019 with git repository, when I push changes in Rider environment only push occurs in local master branch not remote origin, when I push from git bash command line every thing is ok, but I want to push every thing to remote branch in Rider IDE.

[image]
[image]

Comment: From the screenshot, it looks like you've only performed _commit_, but not _push_. Have you actually tried to perform _push_? What was the result? Maybe you had an error message or something?

Comment: Thanks for reply, Yes i performed push too, in several ways and I didn't got any error, plase see updated photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it! as you see in first photo, date and time digits are in local format(Persian or Arabic), This cause error when pushing to remote.

[image]

Comment: Could you please clarify? How did you change the date format there, and which error has occurred when you were trying to push before?

Comment: No error shown at all when pushing, but you can see errors in IDE log files(Help menu then "show log explorer"). My way to change these formats is through windows control panel regional setting, I have to change regional language to English before opening Rider and change it to Persian again after opening Rider IDE :(

Comment: You said there was an error in the logs, but still haven't told more about the error :(

Comment: This is the errpr: 2020-04-12 16:00:03,620 | ERROR | LaterInvocator                 | Illegal Constraint: 'ins 0 ??px 0 0'
Malformed UnitValue: '??px'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal Constraint: 'ins 0 ??px 0 0'
Malformed UnitValue: '??px'
 at net.miginfocom.layout.ConstraintParser.parseLayoutConstraint(Unknown Source)

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't look relevant to Git at all.

Comment: The IDE push dialog dosn't open in this case.